# errno 13 roscreate

Tags: ros, roscreate-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

having trouble with the roscreate command.  its giving me a permissions errror

*****roscreate-pkg enclosure_escape rospy std_msgs irobot_create_2_1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/bin/roscreate-pkg", line 35, in 
roscreate.roscreatepkg.roscreatepkg_main()
File "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/tools/roscreate/src/roscreate/roscreatepkg.py", line 126, in roscreatepkg_main
create_package(package, author_name(), depends, uses_roscpp=uses_roscpp, uses_rospy=uses_rospy)
File "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/tools/roscreate/src/roscreate/roscreatepkg.py", line 63, in create_package
os.makedirs(p)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/enclosure_escape*****

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10126/errno-13-roscreate/) by [younghistory](https://answers.ros.org/users/629/younghistory/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2011-05-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need root permissions to create files in `/opt/ros/diamondback/ros`

Instead, you should create them somewhere in your user directory, for example, `~/ros`

You will need to set your [$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_PACKAGE_PATH) variable to let ROS know to look into that directory. To do so, edit your `/opt/ros/diamondback/setup.sh` file to include these lines:

`export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/ros`

`export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks:${ROS_PACKAGE_PATH}`

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2011-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [younghistory](https://answers.ros.org/users/629/younghistory/) on 2011-05-31**:
haha yep i just realized that...THANKS!!!!!